# Print line if multiple matches

Tags: perl, text

I'm very new to Perl and trying to get this to work. I wish to print 3 specific columns when the contents of column 1 == >0 and column 2 contains "I" (the roman numeral for 1). The following returns all lines containing >0 but NOT containing "I".

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$F[5]" if $F[1] > 0 && $F[0]==/I/' input > output
```

What have I done wrong? I'm also struggling to get it to match the pattern exactly i.e. I do not want it to pull out "II" or "VIII" for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [*binding operator*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) `=~`, not `==` which is a numeric equality test, to test a string against a regex pattern

And you need to *anchor* the start and end of the pattern if you want to specify its entire contents. Read about it in [*Metacharacters*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)

```
$F[0]==/I/
```

should be

```
$F[0] =~ /^I$/
```

or, better, just use a string equality test

```
$F[0] eq 'I'
```